# Get last variables (by the time) from localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to get 10 last variables from local storage.
By "10 last" i mean 10 last added by the time, but i can not find the was to do this.

for example this piece of code:

```
for(var i=0; i<=window.localStorage.length-1; i++){
    var itemKey = localStorage.key(i);
    console.log(itemKey)
}
```

will return me names of all variables in the localstorage, but absolutely in randomly sequence.

there is another way to look what we have in local storage:

```
console.log(window.localStorage);
```

and.. as i'm using Chrome, i'll see all variables sorted by the variable name. nice try google chrome, but i need sort it by the time.

so, does anyone know the way to do this?

Comment: You can't. `localStorage` is an **unsorted** map of keys-> values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to somehow keep track of inserting the elements. You could e.g. use some sort of Linked List to keep track of the insertion order. This is how Java's `LinkedHashMap` keeps track of insertion order, which should work here too. Saidly, I don't know of a good Linked List implementation in JS, but it shouldn't be too hard to find one (or program it by yourself).